# Why I have use Path on Scanner?

Tags: java

Why I can just use the String adress, like `"C:/Users/CleBo/IdeaProjects/test/status.txt"`. Why I have show it in Path, like:

```
Path path = Paths.get ("C:/Users/CleBo/IdeaProjects/test/status.txt").
```

If I write `System.out.println ("C:/Users/CleBo/IdeaProjects/test/status.txt")` it will be the same thing if I  write:

```
System.out.println(path);
```

What the different?

Comment: Let's start with the fact that [`Scanner` accepts a `String` parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.lang.String-), which it will use to as the bases for it's parsing, so passing it a `String` which represents a path means what, exactly?

Comment: The concept you're discussing is something that came late to Java and in some places, some classes will accept a `String` path representation.  This is generally poor design on the part of API authors as it's actual meaning is ambiguous. Instead, they should have supplied functionality which accepted things like, `File` (and now `Path`), `URL` and even `InputStream`, from which the content could be read from

Comment: When you say `new Scanner("Basket full of puppies")` or `new Scanner(Paths.get ("C:/Users/CleBo/IdeaProjects/test/status.txt"))` the meaning of your intentions is very clear.  When you use `System.out.println(Paths.get ("C:/Users/CleBo/IdeaProjects/test/status.txt"));`, `System.out.println` is actually calling the `toString` method of the `Path` object, which generates a readable representation of the object, so, no, they aren't the same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `String` and `Path` overloads do different things:

- The `String` is the data the `Scanner` will tokenize. For example, if you call `new Scanner("I'm a little teapot")`, that scanner will return the tokens `I'm`, `a`, `little` and `teapot`.
- The `Path` is *where to find* the data for to be tokenized. For example, it points to a file containing the data. The tokens it returns will depend upon the contents of the file identified by that path.

Which one you use depends on your use case.